# C# Búsqueda con LIKE de un valor en un textBox dentro de una tabla MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, select

como andan?
Sigo acá tratando de aprender un poco más.
Tengo un Windows Form con un textBox donde ingresar una cadena de texto, y un botón que al presionarlo me debería mostrar los resultados de todos los nombres con esa cadena de texto en un campo de una tabla de una db en mysql arrojados en otro textbox multiline. La tabla se llama usuarios.
El tema es que no se como poner el select dentro del código. Si ejecuto la consulta desde un adm de base de datos me sale bien. Busqué antes en internet, encontré ejemplos, pero me sigue tirando error.

El código es el siguiente:

```
  private void buttonBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conexion.Open();
```

`string cadena = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '%'+@nombre+'%'";

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(cadena, conexion);

        comando.Parameters.Add("@nombre", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxBuscar.Text;

        MySqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();

        while(registro.Read())
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(registro["nombre"].ToString());
            textBox1.AppendText("\n");

        }
        conexion.Close();
    }`

El error que me tira al llegar a la query es:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+'m'+'%'' at line 1'

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que tu cadena esta mal hecha.  Intentalo asi:

```
string cadena = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE @nombre";
```

y luego le añades los wildcards asi:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@nombre", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + textBoxBuscar.Text + "%";
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Funcionó, y además entendí también como funciona el ".Parameters" de una forma que no me había dado cuenta.

Comment: +1 por utilizar consultas parametrizadas en lugar de concatenación de cadenas. Hay que enseñar a los nuevos que ésta es la forma de crear consultas siempre.

Comment: De hecho hay ue enseñar a los "nuevos" que Ado.net no siempre es la mejor opción para acceder a la bdd habiendo tantas opciones mejores (Dapper, Petapoco, Linq2Db, etc)